# jquery variable scope from $.each

Tags: jquery

I have this AJAX call to a php function from jquery.
On change of a `select box` I call do the fetching of data (which comes 100% from php).
I then enter the `$.each` area to process the data into a list.
The list is generates in the `txt` variable, but its scope is only for the `$.each` block.

How can I pass it back to the outside (second `console.log(txt);`)

```
$('#selectMain').on('change', function(){
    var txt = '';
    var argument = $('#selectMain').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './inc/ListManagerScripts.php?argument='+argument,
        success: function(json){
            var countries = [];
            var countries_uuid = [];

            data = $.parseJSON(json);

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                //append countries
                if($.inArray( value.country_uuid, countries_uuid ) == -1 ){
                    countries.push(value.country);
                    countries_uuid.push(value.country_uuid);
                    var txt = txt + addCountry(value.country, value.country_uuid);
                }

                console.log(txt);
            });
            console.log(txt);

        }
    });



    var addCountry = function(country, uuid){
        var snip = '';
        snip = snip + "<div class='expandListHeader'>";
        snip = snip + "<div class='expandListHeaderRow' ctryID='"+uuid+"'>"+country+"</div>";
        snip = snip + "</div>"
        snip = snip + "<div class='expandListContent'>";
        snip = snip + "<div class='expandListContentRow contentCol2'>";
        snip = snip + "</div>";
        snip = snip + "</div>";
        return snip;

    }


});
```

Comment: Declare `txt` before the `$.each`

Comment: Don't you declare `txt` outside the `$.each` block already?

Comment: @APerson Ha! I didn't even notice that. Yeah, so that problem is that it's being _redeclared_ within the `$.each` (as one of the answers states)

Comment: Tip, add `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call. No json parsing is needed than.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
var txt = txt + addCountry(value.country, value.country_uuid);
```

to

```
txt = txt + addCountry(value.country, value.country_uuid);
```

You're redeclaring the variable inside the scope of the $.each callback, so if you take out the declaration you'll be using the one declared inside the on callback.

Edit:

[Relevant Reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: As a side-note, you can use "txt += ..." instead of "txt = txt + ..."

Answer (score 2):

Declare `var txt;` before the function.

Inside the function, use `txt = ...` and not `var txt = ...`

This will then reuse the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared the var txt in the $.each block so its scope is inside the that block.

> To make the txt outside the $.each block change as following

```
var txt;         
$.each(data, function(key, value) {

                //append countries
                if($.inArray( value.country_uuid, countries_uuid ) == -1 ){
                    countries.push(value.country);
                    countries_uuid.push(value.country_uuid);
                     txt = txt + addCountry(value.country, value.country_uuid);
                }

                console.log(txt);
            });
```

You are redeclaring the txt variable again in the $.each function. 
If you want it for all the array elements then you to go with another array.